# Auto integration in TFS branching

Tags: tfs

I have been using IBM Synergy tool in my earlier project for version control system.I like on of the feature which is auto propagation to child branches.

Now I am using TFS and hoping to get the same kind of feature here too but seems like its not available as could not find anything on the web on this.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a feature such as this exists in TFS at the moment (2013). [However, there are some ALM tools that can help you propagate changes to associated branches, the 'Tfs Community Branch Tool extension'.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ce9651af-671c-4148-987f-a91820646031)

There are powershell modules that come with [Team Foundation Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) you can likely cobble something together with as well, if the ALM tool doesn't work out for you. If you happen to be using TFS 2013 build you can inject a PowerShell script in your 'AfterBuild' phase to automate it, should that be something you care to do.

And as always, the TFS object model will provide you all the tools necessary to build out a TFS Build extension or MSBuild extension that would easily provide you with this functionality.